# how to get trigonometric function for Z axis?

Tags: trigonometry

When we find the angle wrt to X axis we use cos theta for x axis and sin theta for Y axis. Similarly how can we get the trigonometric function of Z axis wrt Xaxis?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1):

In a three dimensional "trigonometrical" situation we have three directional cosines instead.

$$ \cos^2 \alpha +\cos^2 \beta +\cos^2 \gamma =1 $$

where a diagonal ( instead of hypotenuse) makes these angles to $ (X,Y,Z)$ axes.